# FastAPI's generated API docs drop down for showing multiple examples for the request body is only showing 1 example

Tags: python, fastapi, swagger-ui, openapi

I am following the FastAPI tutorial, specifically the part about displaying multiple examples: https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/schema-extra-example/.

I copied the code:

```
from typing import Optional

from fastapi import Body, FastAPI
from pydantic import BaseModel

app = FastAPI()


class Item(BaseModel):
    name: str
    description: Optional[str] = None
    price: float
    tax: Optional[float] = None


@app.put("/items/{item_id}")
async def update_item(
    *,
    item_id: int,
    item: Item = Body(
        ...,
        examples={
            "normal": {
                "summary": "A normal example",
                "description": "A **normal** item works correctly.",
                "value": {
                    "name": "Foo",
                    "description": "A very nice Item",
                    "price": 35.4,
                    "tax": 3.2,
                },
            },
            "converted": {
                "summary": "An example with converted data",
                "description": "FastAPI can convert price `strings` to actual `numbers` automatically",
                "value": {
                    "name": "Bar",
                    "price": "35.4",
                },
            },
            "invalid": {
                "summary": "Invalid data is rejected with an error",
                "value": {
                    "name": "Baz",
                    "price": "thirty five point four",
                },
            },
        },
    ),
):
    results = {"item_id": item_id, "item": item}
    return results
```

...exactly as it is displayed on the page and I run it using Uvicorn. On my my screen I do not see any drop down with the 3 examples in the example dictionary of the request body. All I see is a single example value with just the types the fields need to be.

Why would that be and why is this not working for me please?

This is what I should get:

[image: expected Swagger UI]

But this is what I get:

[image: actual Swagger UI]

Comment: Reported here: https://github.com/tiangolo/fastapi/discussions/9958

Answer (score 12):

I am not sure if this could help:
https://github.com/tiangolo/fastapi/pull/1267#issuecomment-762557261
This means two things:

1. examples need to go in  `Item.Config.schema_extra`
2. examples parameter must be referenced to the data from the class

Something like this:

```
class Item(BaseModel):
    name: str
    description: Optional[str] = None
    price: float
    tax: Optional[float] = None

    class Config:
        schema_extra = {
            "examples": {
                "normal": {
                    "summary": "A normal example",
                    "description": "A **normal** item works correctly.",
                    "value": {
                        "name": "Foo",
                        "description": "A very nice Item",
                        "price": 35.4,
                        "tax": 3.2,
                    },
                },
                "converted": {
                    "summary": "An example with converted data",
                    "description": "FastAPI can convert price `strings` to actual `numbers` automatically",
                    "value": {
                        "name": "Bar",
                        "price": "35.4",
                    },
                },
                "invalid": {
                    "summary": "Invalid data is rejected with an error",
                    "value": {
                        "name": "Baz",
                        "price": "thirty five point four",
                    },
                },
            }
        }


@app.put("/items/{item_id}")
async def update_item(
    *,
    item_id: int,
    item: Item = Body(
        None,
        examples=Item.Config.schema_extra["examples"],
    ),
):
    results = {"item_id": item_id, "item": item}
    return results
```

It helped me!

Comment: Doesn't work anymore as of FastAPI 0.99.1.

Comment: @GinoMempin This worked for me with FastAPI 0.96.0.

Answer (score 1):

It was an issue with FastAPI on `>0.99.0` and `<0.103.0`, specifically with [FastAPI's internal update to support OpenAPI 3.1](https://github.com/tiangolo/fastapi/releases/tag/0.99.0) that is now based on the new JSON Schema [that included spec for defining multiple examples](https://json-schema.org/draft/2019-09/json-schema-validation.html#rfc.section.9.5) in the generated `openapi.json`.

Unfortunately, (at this time) Swagger doesn't (yet) fully support this new spec for defining multiple examples, as explained in [a related discussion on Github](https://github.com/tiangolo/fastapi/discussions/9958#discussioncomment-6610067):

> ...the issue is with Swagger UI to fix - FastAPI is passing a valid schema to it, with all of the examples, but it is just that they aren't rendering those examples as a dropdown when they are in the JSON schema.

So, FastAPI fixed it on their side for now on `0.103.0` ([related PR](https://github.com/tiangolo/fastapi/pull/9866)) and it's now explained in the FastAPI docs in https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/schema-extra-example/#swagger-ui-and-openapi-specific-examples:

> Now, as Swagger UI didn't support multiple JSON Schema examples (as of 2023-08-26), users didn't have a way to show multiple examples in the docs.
>
> To solve that, FastAPI `0.103.0` added support for declaring the same old OpenAPI-specific `examples` field with the new parameter `openapi_examples`.

The only change you need to do is to bump your FastAPI version to be at least `0.103.0` and update your code to use `openapi_examples` instead of `examples`:

Old documentation (same as the one in the question):

```
@app.put("/items/{item_id}")
async def update_item(
    *,
    item_id: int,
    item: Item = Body(
        ...,
        examples={               # <-- THIS.
```

New way as of `0.103.0`:

```
@app.put("/items/{item_id}")
async def update_item(
    *,
    item_id: int,
    item: Item = Body(
        openapi_examples={       # <-- THIS.
```

... and the Swagger UI docs should show the dropdown for selecting the examples, as documented. Preferrably, while you are it updating the code, consider using the recommended `Annotated` way: https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/schema-extra-example/#__tabbed_6_1:

```
@app.put("/items/{item_id}")
async def update_item(
    *,
    item_id: int,
    item: Annotated[
        Item,
        Body(
            openapi_examples={   # <-- THIS.
```

**NOTE** that bumping FastAPI to `>0.100.0` *might* also bump your Pydantic dependency to v2, depending on how you are managing dependencies in your project. See FastAPI's [`0.100.0` release notes](https://github.com/tiangolo/fastapi/releases/tag/0.100.0).

---

For more technical details, see:

- Discussions on Github:

  - ["Body with Multiple Examples" only showing single example v0.100.1 #9958](https://github.com/tiangolo/fastapi/discussions/9958)
  - [Multiple request examples not working using pydantic](https://github.com/tiangolo/fastapi/discussions/9794)
- Related PRs on FastAPI:

  - [Multiple Body Examples regression in v0.100](https://github.com/tiangolo/fastapi/pull/9866)